# Join subqueries without USING

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have query like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    [fldID],
    [fldValue]
            FROM
                (
                    (
                        SELECT
                            alias1.[fldID],
                            alias1.[fldValue]
                        FROM someT as alias1
                            ....
                    )
                ) AS subQuery_1
            INNER JOIN
            (
                SELECT
                    alias1.[fldID],
                    alias1.[fldValue]
                FROM someT as alias1
                    ...
            ) AS subQuery_2 USING( fldID, fldValue)
```

It works fine in MySQL, but SQL Server do not support USING. So I must to use JOIN like this:

```
ON [subQuery_1].[fldID] = [subQuery_2].[fldID] 
AND [subQuery_1].[fldValue] = [subQuery_2].[fldValue]
```

But this query leads to errors:

```
Ambiguous column name fldID 
Ambiguous column name fldValue
```

So, how I can implement such kind of JOIN in SQL Server?

Comment: you have to adjust your `SELECT` statement to say whether you are selecting from `subQuery_1` or `subQuery_2`

Comment: Show us the query you are trying on SQL Server that doesn't work.  Just showing us a working MySQL query and then saying you change it somehow for SQL Server but it throws errors, doesn't help us because we no longer know exactly what the new non-working query is.  And it's the details that matter for syntax errors like this.

Comment: @RBarryYoung This question has everything that is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to specify from which subquery you take those columns from (it doesn't matter which one you take in your case as you join on both columns)

```
SELECT DISTINCT
subQuery_1.[fldID],
subQuery_1.[fldValue]
        FROM
            (
                (
                    SELECT
                        alias1.[fldID],
                        alias1.[fldValue]
                    FROM someT as alias1
                        ....
                )
            ) AS subQuery_1
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                alias1.[fldID],
                alias1.[fldValue]
            FROM someT as alias1
                ...
        ) AS subQuery_2 
 ON [subQuery_1].[fldID] = [subQuery_2].[fldID] 
 AND [subQuery_1].[fldValue] = [subQuery_2].[fldValue]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your query you are not adding table alias in final select. You need to specify which column coming from which table like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    subQuery_1.[fldID],
    subQuery_1.[fldValue]
            FROM
                (
                    (
                        SELECT
                            alias1.[fldID],
                            alias1.[fldValue]
                        FROM someT as alias1
                            ....
                    )
                ) AS subQuery_1
            INNER JOIN
            (
                SELECT
                    alias1.[fldID],
                    alias1.[fldValue]
                FROM someT as alias1
                    ...
            ) AS subQuery_2 
            on [subQuery_1].[fldID] = [subQuery_2].[fldID] 
AND [subQuery_1].[fldValue] = [subQuery_2].[fldValue]
```